# The ODS should have the schema of the DW or not?

Tags: data-warehouse

I am creating a datawarehouse and was thinking if the ODS needs to follow the schema of the dw or its just simple db to extract data from to the dw.

Thank you

Comment: The ODS should be structured to best support the use cases you have for your ODS

Comment: And the "O" in ODS stands for Operational, which typically means its schema should closely follow the schema of the source systems.  The transformations in the DW typically are costly, lossy, and time-consuming, all bad things for an ODS.